# Selenium IDE I'm stuck with a conditional sentence if

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to make a conditional sentence with if I'm a bit stuck with how to do it in Selenium IDE.

I want it to be made as follows:
For example, that once I have a coupon it will click cancel.
If there is no coupon code is put my coupon code

```
| clickAndWait | link=Cancel |
| type | id=code | 123QA |
```

Comment: Aren't that two separate test-cases? One for the cancel and one for the coupon. Why do you want to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275354/using-if-else-in-selenium-ide) you can use the [Flow Control plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/) listed on [the official Selenium IDE download page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Personally I would not use the Selenium IDE for complex website interactions, just as a proof of concept. Implementing Selenium with a programming language is much more flexible for complex cases.

Other reads:

- GotoIf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498966/how-can-i-organize-if-else-in-selenium-ide